# proxy with create react app - how to configure it?

Tags: reactjs, express, http-proxy

I have a problem with configuring proxy... Right know, I have this:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

    module.exports = function (app) {
      app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
          target: 'http://localhost:5000/',
          changeOrigin: true,
        })
      );
    };
```

and it works fine when I do some request for example on localhost:3000/products

```
export const fetchProducts = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios('/api/products');
      const data = await response.data;

      dispatch(getProducts(data));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

};

but when I go on localhost:3000/**products**/654684516 and here try to delete a product with this code

```
const handleDelete = async (e) => {
    axios({ method: 'delete', url: `products/${match.params.id}` });
  };
```

I got  http://localhost:3000/**products**/products/654684516

If I try this

```
 const handleDelete = async (e) => {
    axios({ method: 'delete', url: `/${match.params.id}` });
  };
```

I got this http://localhost:3000/654684516

I've tried with rewritePath, but didnt't find the solution. I've searched through the web and found nothing. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What happens if you put a forward slash before products in handle delete? `/products`

Comment: I've got this http://localhost:3000/products/646846 which is actually closer to what i supposed to have.. the question is how to change 3000 to 5000

Comment: that was it... i supposed to have `/api/products/${match.params.id}` in delete method (slash was missing). i cant belive i wasted so much time on it. thanks

Comment: Glad you got it sorted